# how to send details to mail in javascript code

Tags: javascript

I want to send all input data which filled in the contact form.

contact form in javascript

---

```
function sendMail() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
      data: {
        'key': 'YOUR API KEY HERE',
        'message': {
          'from_email': 'YOUR@EMAIL.HERE',
          'to': [
              {
                'email': 'RECIPIENT@EMAIL.HERE',
                'name': 'RECIPIENT NAME (OPTIONAL)',
                'type': 'to'
              }
            ],
          'autotext': 'true',
          'subject': 'YOUR SUBJECT HERE!',
          'html': 'YOUR EMAIL CONTENT HERE! YOU CAN USE HTML!'
        }
      }
     }).done(function(response) {
       console.log(response); // if you're into that sorta thing
     });
}
```

Comment: Hey there and welcome at SO. Please format your code so that people can read it quickly and then help you.

Comment: you'll want to replace `YOUR EMAIL CONTENT HERE! YOU CAN USE HTML!` - without seeing the `<form>` it's not easy to help

Comment: You may want to take a look at [EmailJS](http://emailjs.com?src=so), which allows sending email using pre-built templates directly from Javascript [disclosure - I'm one of the creators]

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `key/value` pairs with values from `textboxes` like below

```
{
  ...
  'subject': $('#txtSubject').val(),
  ...
}
```

Here, `txtSubject` is `id` of subject's `textbox`. Like this you can replace all the fields you want to send to API.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your query, I persume a solution

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
    'key': <your_key>,
    'form-data': form.serialize()
    }
 })
```

Your will get all the keyword of input name with value inside the `form-data` dictionary.